Why MapStruct dosen't return the modified list from @BeforeMapping as it should be
I am trying to map (using MapStruct) non null elements only from UserDTO list to Users list.
It is true that toEntity(UserDTO userDTO) method checks null value but the created list for collection mapping returns a list with the initial DTO list size( that may contain null element too).
That is why i used @BeforeMapping as below:
@BeforeMapping
default  void filterNonNullDTO(List<UserDTO>  userDTO){

    userDTO=userDTO.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

The generated implementation is this:
    @Override
public List<User> toEntities(List<UserDTO> userDtos) {

    filterNonNullDTO( userDtos );

    if ( userDtos == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>( userDtos.size() );
    for ( UserDTO userDTO : userDtos ) {
        list.add( toEntity( userDTO ) );
    }

    return list;
}

I writed a Junit5 test for this case but it dosen't pass.The expected list size should be 1 but it's 2. I debuged the test but the size returned by the mappes is always 2 not 1 as it should be since filterNonNullDTO removes null elements.
Test :
    @Test
   void  mapUserDTOsToUserShouldReturnNonNullUsers(){
        List<AdminUserDTO> userDTOs= new ArrayList<>();
        userDTOs.add(userDto);
        userDTOs.add(null);
        List<User> users= userMapper.toEntities(userDTOs);
        assertThat(users).isNotEmpty().size().isEqualTo(1);

    }

Test result: expected: 1 but was: 2
Could you figure out what am i doing wrong?

Your filterNonNullDTO method does not do what you think it does.  It does not update the original list, only the reference parameter that was passed to it.

Is the list modifiable? Perhaps you want userDTO.removeIf(Objects::isNull)

@Slaw Thank you, that worked. I wonder what is the difference, why removeIf works on the real list referenced by userDTO and what i did before does not ?!

@Islam The stream is creating a new list instance, and Java is always pass-by-value (where for reference types, the value is the reference) so reassigning the method parameter has no effect outside the method. In contrast, removeIf modifies the list instance in place.
